# Interpretting relative probabilities based on Boltzmann's probability distribution?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I understand that Boltzmann's probability distribution gives the relative probability of one microscopic state in comparison to the other (P1/P2) but I don't know how exactly to understand this.

For example when looking at Hydrogen's ground state and Hydrogen's first excited state at some temperature T, let's say that P1/P2 is 0.3 what does this mean in words? Does this mean that at whatever temperature T, P1 happesn 30% of the time? Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?

Comment: For the example you gave, a ratio of (P1/P0) equal to .3 would suggest that you have more hydrogen molecule in the ground state and specifically would have 3 in the excited state for every 10 in the ground state.